# Tetrahedron Volume Analysis using Triple Integrals and all three system of coordinate

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Good afternoon,day fellow Exchanger!

I'm working on an assignement since last night and I am really losing over sometime I can't figure out. Here is the problem;

Evaluate : $\displaystyle \iiint\limits_e z^2 dV$

Given 3 vertices, $(3,0,0)$, $(0,3,0)$, $(0,0,3)$, $(0,0,0)$, I need to calculate the solid bounded under the plane (Pyramid/Tetrahedron) formed by those vertices and outside the unit sphere centered at the origin. 
I need to format 3 approach, (Cartesian,Cylindrical and Spherical [I know this is not the natural way of interpreting the problem but hey what can I say?:P])
So far I figured out both Cartesian and Cylindrical as the answer are exactly the same thing. But I have been looking over it over and over again to find a way to write it as a Spherical and I just can't get any plausible answer.

Here's what I worked out so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In spherical coordinates:
$$
x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta,\quad
y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta,\quad
z=\rho\cos\phi.
$$
The equation of the plane $x+y+z=3$ gives then:
$$
\rho={3\over\sin\phi(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)+\cos\phi}
$$
and the integration over $\rho$ must then be carried out from $\rho=1$ to the above value.
The integration limits for $\phi$ and $\theta$ are quite obvious, as both can vary between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: I have come accross this approach too but the result I had was a bit off the result I had with the other 2 systems. Is it possible that the answer won't be exactly the same? And thank you very much!

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was an 18 inch behind the textbook! I didn't had the good input for my limits of phi. Well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a check, you can try to integrate 1 in order to get the volume of the region, which is obviously $(27-\pi)/6$.